# Tag depth and max tag deph of HTML DOM with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am wondering if something like this is possible with Jsoup for html pages.

HTML Document where company and staff are considered html tags:

```
<company> 
        <staff id="1">
                <firstname>George</firstname>
                <lastname>Deren</lastname>
                <nickname>Revan</nickname>
                <salary>50000</salary>
                <age>24</age>
        <extra>
            <test>123</test>
        </extra>
```

For example the bracket would contain the DOM depth of that specific tag.

```
company[1]
staff[2]
firstname[3]
lastname[3]
nickname[3]
salary[3]
age[3]
extra[3]
test[4]
```

The deepest level is : 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node visitor for this. It has the depth value. Suppose your xml is stored in data.xml file then this program prints what you want

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;

public class JsoupDepth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File input = new File("data.xml");
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new FileInputStream(input), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
            doc.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
                public void head(Node node, int depth) {
                    if(!(node instanceof TextNode)) {
                        System.out.println(node.nodeName() + "[" + depth + "]");
                    }
                }
                public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```